# listing specific citrix sessions in datagridview

Tags: powershell, datagridview, citrix

I am trying to list all active citrix sessions for a specific user in a datagridview.
It can list all sessions fine, but I want it to skip sessions for which are already listed in the datagridview and instead only view the BrowserName for them.

This script works OK, if I am listing for only 2 sessions. But as soon as I try and query a user who has more than 3 sessions running it just stops working.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this working? or any better approach to storing the sessions which would make my handling of them easier?

```
 function List-CitrixSessions{
 param([string]$userEntry)
 $datagridview1.Rows.Clear()
 $sessions = Get-XASession -ComputerName $CitrixDataCollector -Account GLOBAL\$userEntry
 foreach ($session in $sessions){ 
     if ($servers -contains $session.serverName){ 
        $datagridview1.Rows.Add($null,$session.BrowserName,$null,$null,$null,$null) 
        } 
        else{ 
        $servers += $session.serverName 
        $dataGridView1.Rows.Add($session.State,$session.BrowserName,$session.serverName,$session.SessionID,$session.ClientName,$session.ClientIPV4) 
        } 
    }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Missd to clear the servers variable before running script, and therefore causing a bunch of bugs.